# Chrome compatibility with bootstrap vs edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

Chrome
[image: chrome]

Edge
[image: edge]

So the problem is obvious but I don't know the cause, I wish I could narrow it down to a specific question but I can't, it's just wrong for seemingly no reason

https://ayresplastering.co.uk/ is the website

I've tried inspecting the console running it through chatgpt new cdn links for bootstrap, checking for any issues in the code, even resizing it in edge into mobile mode I just can't understand why it's different in chrome lastly on my safari mobile it's fine but my partners and it's the same as the chrome result

code below

https://github.com/ayresplastering/AyresPlastering-website

Comment: For me both Edge and Chrome have the problem. Check your browsers are updated. Also share your codes so that we can see what you have.

Comment: https://github.com/ayresplastering/AyresPlastering-website Thanks pal

Also both browsers are up to date

@SabinChacko

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `display: flex;` property from `body`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: No change unfortunately I'm hoping it's something smalllike that

Comment: @AlecAyre now It's Working in the Edge https://prnt.sc/MRbpeG3vNJRv

Comment: this is so odd, it was fine in edge before for me but the issue is still there in chrome for me, just loads in vertical slices

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your chrome browser...
 also, clear your browser cache before check

Comment: Correct it was the cache, thanks a bunch!

Comment: So your issue is resolved now??

Comment: Yes thank you! just trying to figure out how to mark as answered, it's been a long time since using stack overflow

Comment: check here https://prnt.sc/2orzfdLhUtwB

Comment: Yeah just got it, I can't upvote as it's a new account but thank you very much, it was driving me mad!

Answer (score -1):

Add `fixed-top` to your `<nav`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Wrap your `<section>`s in `<main>` tag

```
<main>
        <!-- Instagram Section -->
        <section id="instagram" class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <div class="row" id="instagram-container">
                <!-- Posts will be loaded here by JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <!-- Facebook -->
            <a style="color: #3b5998;" href="https://www.facebook.com/AyresTraditionalPlastering/" role="button"><i
                    class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg"></i></a>
            <!-- Instagram -->
            <a style="color: #ac2bac;" href="https://www.instagram.com/ayresplastering/" role="button"><i
                    class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
        </section>

        <!-- Traditional Plastering Section -->
        <section id="traditional" class="container">
            <h2>Traditional Plastering</h2>
            <p>Our traditional plastering services include a variety of time-honored techniques and materials. We
                specialize
                in lime work, heritage work, wattle and daub, as well as clay and earth plastering. Our skilled team
                combines craftsmanship and attention to detail, ensuring the preservation of historical buildings and
                the
                creation of stunning finishes in modern properties.</p>
            <!-- Add images or a gallery showcasing your traditional plastering work -->
        </section>
        <!-- Fibrous Plastering Section -->
        <section id="fibrous" class="container">
            <h2>Fibrous Plastering</h2>
            <p>Fibrous plastering is a technique that involves the use of plaster reinforced with materials such as
                hessian
                and timber laths. This approach allows for the creation of intricate decorative elements, such as
                cornices,
                ceiling roses, and ornamental moldings. Our expert plasterers can craft bespoke designs that add a touch
                of
                elegance and sophistication to any space, whether it's a grand entrance or a cozy living room.</p>
            <!-- Add images or a gallery showcasing your fibrous plastering work -->
        </section>

        <!-- Rendering Section -->
        <section id="rendering" class="container">
            <h2>Rendering</h2>
            <p>We offer a comprehensive range of rendering services, including monocouche, lime, sand and cement, and
                thin
                coat render systems. Our team is skilled in creating various finishes, such as ashlar, quoins, alpine,
                bagged, plain faced, and pitted finishes. Whether you're looking to improve the appearance of your
                property's exterior, enhance its durability, or increase its energy efficiency, our rendering solutions
                cater to your needs and preferences.</p>
            <!-- Add images or a gallery showcasing your rendering work -->
        </section>
        <!-- Modern Plastering Section -->
        <section id="modern" class="container">
            <h2>Modern Plastering</h2>
            <p>Modern plastering techniques have evolved to meet the demands of today's construction industry. Our
                services
                include float and set, dot and dab, patching and repairing, and reskimming. We use high-quality
                materials
                and state-of-the-art tools to deliver smooth, even surfaces that are ready for painting or wallpapering.
                Whether it's a new build or a renovation project, our modern plastering solutions ensure a professional
                finish and lasting results.</p>
            <!-- Add images or a gallery showcasing your modern plastering work -->
        </section>

        <!-- Floor Screeding Section -->
        <section id="screeding" class="container">
            <h2>Floor Screeding</h2>
            <p>Floor screeding is essential for creating level, durable, and thermally efficient flooring. We offer a
                variety of screeding solutions, including lime, earth, and sand and cement screeds, suitable for both
                residential and commercial properties. Our experienced team works closely with clients to choose the
                most
                appropriate materials and techniques, ensuring a strong foundation for your flooring and a comfortable,
                energy-efficient environment.</p>
            <!-- Add images or a gallery showcasing your floor screeding work -->
        </section>

    </main>
```

That's all you need to do (In a Bootstrap way)!

Comment: Thank you so much, you're both absolute stars!

Comment: So weird, that fixed the navbar in edge but not chrome! It's driving me mad!

Comment: No chance! It will work in all browsers. Try to open Chrom Incognito window,

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it but this is the exact way Bootstrap Layout should work. If you want to edit the core css then what is the purpose of using Bootstrap?